# PyQt drag and drop outside app into Windows file explorer?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to create files by dragging from a QListWidget into the OS file explorer (Windows 10 in my case), is this possible? So in the widget below, I want dragging "one" and "two" from the list onto a folder in the system file explorer to create two files named "one.txt" and "two.txt" containing the text "one" and "two" respectively

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class DragTest(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.addItems(['one', 'two', 'three'])
        self.setSelectionMode(self.MultiSelection)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() or QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = DragTest()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the [`startDrag()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#startDrag) method and add the urls to the QDrag instance.

```
class DragTest(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    # ...
    def startDrag(self, actions):
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        indexes = self.selectedIndexes()
        mime = self.model().mimeData(indexes)
        urlList = []
        for index in indexes:
            urlList.append(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(index.data()))
        mime.setUrls(urlList)
        drag.setMimeData(mime)
        drag.exec_(actions)
```

Note that I'm just using the `index.data()` since you used the full path for the item name, but you might prefer to set a specific data role for the full url in case, for example, you want to show only the file name:

```
FullPathRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

class DragTest(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    # ...
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls():
            e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            e.accept()
            fpath_list = []
            for url in e.mimeData().urls():
                fpath_list.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))

            for fpath in fpath_list:
                print(f'IMPORT {fpath}')
                fileName = QtCore.QFileInfo(fpath).fileName()
                item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(fileName)
                item.setData(FullPathRole, fpath)
                self.addItem(fpath)

    def startDrag(self, actions):
        # ...
            urlList.append(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(index.data(FullPathRole)))
```

Also note that you are missing the parentheses in the `if e.mimeData().hasUrls():` check.

Comment: I think I was unclear in my original question - I don't want to just copy existing files from one location to another. I want to be able to create files when the user drags and drops from the QListWidget into the file explorer and I want to set the file name and contents based on what item they dragged. I edited my question down and removed my extra code which made things less clear