# PyQt5 drag and drop into system file explorer (with delayed encoding)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to let users create files by dragging items from PyQt to the system file explorer. Since some of the files will be very large, I also need to delay setting the data to when the user finishes the drop instead of immediately on start of drag.

This example seems to be what I need: https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/draganddrop-delayedencoding.html

I tried converting that to a simple PyQt5 version where dragging a QPushButton into a folder will create a plain text file, but it's not working for me... when I run it dropping does nothing and my cursor looks like this:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import typing
import time


class MimeData(QtCore.QMimeData):
    dataRequested = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def formats(self) -> typing.List[str]:
        return QtCore.QMimeData.formats(self) + ["text/plain"]

    def retrieveData(self, mime_type: str, preferred_type: QtCore.QVariant.Type):
        self.dataRequested.emit(mime_type)
        return QtCore.QMimeData.retrieveData(self, mime_type, preferred_type)


class SourceWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    mimeData: MimeData = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Drag Me")
        button.pressed.connect(self.start_drag)

        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def create_data(self, mime_type):
        if mime_type == "text/plain":
            time.sleep(0.25)  # Simulate large file
            self.mimeData.setData("text/plain", b"my text file contents")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_drag(self):
        self.mimeData = MimeData()
        self.mimeData.dataRequested.connect(self.create_data)

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(self.mimeData)
        drag.exec(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() or QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = SourceWidget()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can have an easy answer to that (as to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887847/pyqt-drag-and-drop-outside-app-into-windows-file-explorer/63888356). Dropping outside Qt is not easy to achieve, as it completely depends on the platform management of drag&drop. Long story made short: you cannot do it with PyQt; at least, not easily. Nonetheless there are still some issues within your code anyway, most importantly you used the `pyqtSlot()` decorator without arguments, but `create_data` requires a string.

Comment: What you *could* try to do is to create a temporary file (if the source doesn't exist yet), and add the url for that temporary file to the mimeData url list. In the meantime, just before starting the drag operation, you can create a thread that separately creates the file, and delay the drop (within `retrieveData()`) until the data creation is completed using a simple while loop that awaits until the thread is (successfully) completed. PS: about the `pyqtSlot()` issue, remember that those decorators are rarely required, so if you don't really need them (as in this case), just avoid them.

Comment: What about the link then? Did they remove this functionality in Qt5 or something? Or is it a problem with PyQt vs Qt? https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/draganddrop-delayedencoding.html

Comment: Mmmh, the link shows how to set a mimeData contaning an image; what the platform does with that completely depends on how the platform manages drag&drop operations according to the drag data. I don't know what platform you're using, I'm going to guess you're under Windows (you never specified that, which was somehow important) and I can only suppose that that platform automatically *suggests* to create a new file with the image data according to the drag contents. In fact, if you look closely, the `createData` function only updates the mime contents, no file is physically created.

Comment: I don't know what kind of data are you going to create, but if it's a custom one, I believe that the only solution is to create a temporary file with the data you're going to use, provide the appropriate `QUrl` for that file and connect the drop action in a way that the source file is removed just after the drop has been completed.

Comment: Well this is my application: https://www.screencast.com/t/MqDCsrzwvEyP And my goal is to have users drag out names from the navbar at the left and drop in their file explorer and have it save a .csv file of the corresponding data. I'm on Windows 10. I assumed whatever OS mime-magic that happens to make their demo save an image would also work if I used plain text or CSV in the mimeData instead, but it's not clear to me how it works. The temp file does sound like a good way to do what I want though, do you have a link to an example of that?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem like you're going to need too much work for that: just use python's own `with open(path, 'w') as f: f.write(data)` and return the path after that, then construct the QUrl using [`fromLocalFile(path)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromLocalFile) and add the path to the urls as a list. I don't know how Qt behaves under windows with that; if the dropEvent returns just after passing the data to the system (as I think it does), you'll need to find a way to ensure that the copying has been completed before removing the temp file, but be aware that you have to consider ->

Comment: -> the possibility that the target file already exists, and I frankly don't know how you could work around that case. As said, the main problem is that you don't have control over the target of the drop action if it happens outside Qt, so the only possibility is to use platform modules (in that case, win32, maybe) to find a safer solution. Otherwise, the only possibility is to continuously create temporary files, hoping that the temporary folder will be cleared on the next reboot or application start.

Comment: I'm not sure where I would put your code snippet, I don't think I can access the drop destination path anywhere... that's why all the examples I see use mimeData. The dropEvent method of a widget runs when you drop an item on it, but if the user drops an item outside of PyQt on the system explorer there is no widget and no dropEvent.

Comment: No. That path is for the temporary file, and you have to create that file when the drag event is started or, at least, within the (first call to) `retrieveData()` function, and you must return a `QUrl` with the temporary file path, so that the platform is able to copy its contents.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I managed to get the first part working but still can't get the delayed encoding working... will keep at it and update if I do. These seem relevant but no easy answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724252/qt-4-x-how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-onto-the-desktop-or-into-a-folder and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804272/qt-drag-and-drop-to-windows-explorer-how-do-i-know-the-dropped-destination-path/38846300 posted my current code as an answer for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with for dragging and dropping files from PyQt5 into file explorer, and only having the file write once the mouse is released to finalize the drop.

```
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

import tempfile
import os

# Use win32api on Windows because the pynput and mouse packages cause lag
# https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/390
if os.name == 'nt':
    import win32api


    def mouse_pressed():
        return win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) not in [0, 1]
else:
    import mouse


    def mouse_pressed():
        return mouse.is_pressed()


class DelayedMimeData(QtCore.QMimeData):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.callbacks = []

    def add_callback(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)

    def retrieveData(self, mime_type: str, preferred_type: QtCore.QVariant.Type):
        mp = mouse_pressed()
        if not mp:
            for callback in self.callbacks.copy():
                self.callbacks.remove(callback)
                callback()

        return QtCore.QMimeData.retrieveData(self, mime_type, preferred_type)


class Navigator(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setHeaderLabels(["Name"])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['Test1'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['Test2'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['Test3'])

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.DragDrop)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)

    def startDrag(self, actions):
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        names = [item.text(0) for item in self.selectedItems()]
        mime = DelayedMimeData()
        path_list = []
        for name in names:
            path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'DragTest', name + '.txt')
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
            print(path)

            def write_to_file(path=path, name=name, widget=self):
                with open(path, 'w+') as f:
                    print("Writing large file(s)...")
                    time.sleep(2)  # Sleep to simulate long file write
                    f.write(f"Contents of {name}")

            mime.add_callback(write_to_file)
            path_list.append(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path))

        mime.setUrls(path_list)
        mime.setData('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist',
                     self.mimeData(self.selectedItems()).data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'))
        drag.setMimeData(mime)
        drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
        super().startDrag(actions)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

nav = Navigator()
nav.show()
app.exec_()
```